# error flutter when build project pipeline.yml?

Tags: flutter, build, devops

error in azure devops when

Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                   0.8s
[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Hadish\flutter\bin\flutter.bat' failed with exit code 1

[Flutter Extention fro azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter)

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?